# Python: Confliction between pandas and subprocess

Tags: pandas, numpy, ubuntu, pip, subprocess

I have been working on this python file for a while with pandas, numpy, cpuinfo and so on. The code works perfect until I imported call from subprocess. Then it started showing the error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I have tried by uninstalling and reinstalling pandas multiple times. It works fine if I remove the subprocess, sometimes once/twice with the subprocess and pandas. But it's not stable.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Editor: VSCode
pip3: 22.0.2
python3 3.10.12

Can anyone explain this? Or any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it just importing subprocess that causes this problem, or do you also have to use something from subprocess to cause the issue?

Comment: I am using Call from Subprocess @NickODell